# Why is my method printing out the last element of the list when its not supposed to?

Tags: java, singly-linked-list

Using a singly linked list, I am returning a Set c containing elements found only in set A and not in set B.

Set A contains : 30, 20, item2, item1, 10, 26

Set B contains: 88, item3, 30, item4, 26, 100

A.complement(B); should give an output of { 20 item2 item1 10  },

but I'm getting { 20 item2 item1 10 26 } and '26' shouldn't be in the set.
I can't figure out what's wrong even after drawing out a diagram of the list.

```
public boolean otherContain(Object obj) { // returns true if object is
                                            // inside singly linked list
    Node cur = head.next;

    while (cur != null) {
        if (cur.object.equals(obj))
            return true;
        else
            cur = cur.next;
    }

    return false;
}


public Set complement(Set a) {// return set containing elements only in A
                                // not shared with B
    Set c = new Set();
    Node curC = c.head;
    Node cur = head.next;

    while (cur != null) {

        if (a.otherContain(cur.object)) {
            cur = cur.next;
        } else if (!a.otherContain(cur.object)) {
            curC.next = cur;
            curC = curC.next;
            cur = cur.next;
        }
    }
    return c;
}
```

*************Updated Working Method************************

```
    public Set complement(Set a) {// return set containing elements only in A
                                // not shared with B
    Set c = new Set();
    Node newNode = c.head;
    Node cur = head.next;

    while (cur != null) {

        if (a.otherContain(cur.object)) {
            cur = cur.next;
        } else if (!a.otherContain(cur.object)) {
            newNode.next = new Node(cur.object, newNode.next);
            cur = cur.next;
        }
    }
    return c;
}
```

Comment: A singly linked set, it must be homework.  I suggest you use your debugger to help you debug your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are reusing the Nodes of the input Set in the output Set, so the final Node you add to the output Set - 10 - still refers to the last Node of the input Set - 26. You should create new Nodes for the output Set.

```
public Set complement(Set a) {
    Set c = new Set();
    Node curC = c.head;
    Node cur = head.next;

    while (cur != null) {  
        if (!a.otherContain(cur.object)) {
            Node newNode = new Node();
            newNode.object = cur.object;
            newNode.next = null;
            curC.next = newNode;
            curC = curC.next;
        }
        cur = cur.next;
    }
    return c;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, followed your advice before you posted the code and it worked!

Comment: @hobbes Good for you! It's always better to write the code yourself.